# Mongo query json object with dates

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I try to dynamically create a `mongo` query with dates.

This is a part of a `JSON` query I produced:

`{"$or":[{"createdAt":{"$gte":"2017-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"}},{"modifiedAt":{"$gte":"2017-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"}}]}`

but it does not work.

This is a part of code which stands behind it:

`let result = {$or: [{createdAt: {$lte: new Date(date)}}, {modifiedAt: {$lte: new Date(date)}}]};`

Spent 3 hours trying to find a solution. My understanding is that `$lte` here tries to compare `mongo` date object with a string describing date in ISO format. And it does not work well.

I do not know how to create a proper `JSON` object being a `mongo` query containing dates.

Please help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query Mongo with date range, you have to use a standard Date format (ISO-8601). To achieve this, try with moment:

```
        let date ="2019-02-22"; //for example, in my apis, you can set multiple type of date (YYYY-MM-DD, YYYYMMDD, DD-MM-YYYY,..) but date format with / is forbidden.
        let query = {$or:[{createdAt: {$lte: moment(date).format()}}, {modifiedAt:{$gte: moment(date).format()}}] //pass parameter to format, in this case it will use the default locale format
```

Like this you are setting a query. IMO querying on date range with "OR" condition is not useful: usually a date query in is "AND" condition (if you are querying on a single date, your query will be: greater than today or lower than today -> everything)

Comment: The code you proposed creates what I already have and it does not work: `db.getCollection('videos').find({"$or":[{"createdAt":{"$gte":"2017-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"}},{"modifiedAt":{"$gte":"2017-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"}}]})`